# Error 404 : The server can not find the requested page: /customer/account/login (port 443)

Tags: magento-1.9

I'm getting this error when I try to access one page checkout and my account page on my website. I'm using Magento 1.9. All pages, except those two are working fine.

What issue can cause this, and how can I resolve it?

Comment: Are you still having issues Paula?

Answer (score 0):

The error is probably down to the fact that the checkout will by default try to use secure (https) URLs whereas, again by default, most of the rest of the site will not.  For a live site, you will need to set up SSL and get your SSL certificates in order.

For a local/testing/development environment, this is a pain.  One way to get around it in this situation is to change your secure base URL either in the Magento admin (system > general > web > secure) or directly in the database (core_config table) to use HTTP instead of https. Another is to set the box (in the same location) that says "Use Secure URLs in Frontend" to No.

This should allow you test the process.  Do NOT do this live - get your certs sorted out.

UPDATE

One thing that might be possible is that, if you are using Google Chrome to test locally, there is an option in the Chrome flags area to:

> "Allow invalid certificates for resources loaded from localhost. Mac,
>   Windows, Linux, Chrome OS, Android Allows requests to localhost over
>   HTTPS even when an invalid certificate is presented. #allow-insecure-localhost"

You can find this about 3-5ths of the way down the list in the Google Chrome flags settings.  Visit chrome://flags/  in the browser to get the list.  This may help with this.